# Numpy subarray affect the original 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I created this `2D array` with `numpy`:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>np.random.seed(0)
>>>x2 = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 4))
>>>print(x2)
[[5 0 3 3]
 [7 9 3 5]
 [2 4 7 6]]
```

Then I created another subarray from `x2`

```
>>>x2_sub = x2[:2, :2]
>>>print(x2_sub)
[[5 0]
 [7 9]]
```

Now if I modify this subarray, the original array is changed!!:

```
>>>x2_sub[0, 0] = 99
>>>print(x2_sub)
[[99 0]
 [7 9]]
>>>print(x2)
[[99  0  3  3]
 [ 7  9  3  5]
 [ 2  4  7  6]]
```

I don't want the original array to change. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing worng ?

Comment: slicing will return a view of ```x2```. If you want to explicitly make a copy you can do ```x2_sub = x2_sub.copy()``` before modifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slices in numpy create a *view* unlike Python lists. Use `.copy()` to explicitly create a copy:

```
x2_sub = x2[:2, :2].copy()
```